# No visible @ interface for 'NSMutableArray' declares the selector 'shuffledArray'

Tags: xcode6, nsarray, shuffle

This should be simple.  All I want to do is randomize an NSArray.  I found this neat little plugin to do just that called "shuffledArray". https://github.com/bryanluby/NSArray-Shuffle

So I should be finished right now.  I imported NSArray+Shuffle.h

```
#import "NSArray+Shuffle.h"
```

I added a shuffledArray interface:

```
@interface TipCollectionViewController ()
{
    AJNotificationView *panel;
    NSString * query;
   // CLLocationManager * locationManager;
    NSMutableArray * _entries;
   // NSArray *shuffledArray;
    int page;
    int c_page;
    NSArray *mostPopular;
    NSArray *ranDom;
    NSRange blueRange;


    //int pageNum;
    //NSString *phpLink;
    NSMutableData *responsePlaceData;
}
-(NSMutableArray *)shuffledArray;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet CollectionLayout *tipsLayout;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImageView *menuImage;
//@property SESpringBoard *board2;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *itemCounts;
@end
```

...yet when I try to randomize an Array:

```
ranDom = [_entries shuffledArray];
```

It tells me that no NSMutableArray interface called shuffledArray exists.

Any idea where I'm going wrong? This is giving me a headache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll do the honors...

FIRST off the guy's code, instructions, and github page are all wrong.

```
ranDom = [_entries shuffledArray];
```

...was never going to work.

Because in the source code his method is actually:

```
bjl_shuffledArray
```

So...

```
ranDom = [_entries bjl_shuffledArray];
```

works.

The second problem was actually my fault.

I was writing to:

```
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
```

...when I should've been writing to:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
```

So the solution is:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
{
    ranDom = [_entries bjl_shuffledArray];   
    mostPopular = [[_entries reverseObjectEnumerator]allObjects];
    if (isChangeData){
        NSLog(@"Most Popular");
        dataLand = mostPopular;

    }
    else if(isChangeData2){
        NSLog(@"Random");
        dataLand = ranDom;

    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"All");
        dataLand = _entries;
    }
    Place *p = [dataLand objectAtIndex:indexPath.item];
}
```

With "dataLand" being another NSArray I came up with.

Now it works!  I really need to start getting some more sleep.